# appending an array in to jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to append an array items[] in my webpage using jquery template.

```
items=[{'name' => 'test',
        'values' => 
           [
            {
            'ver' => 2,
            'count' => 469,
           },
           {
            'ver' => 2,
            'count' => 445,
            }]},

        {'name' => 'test2',
        'values' => 
           [
           {
            'ver' => 4,
            'count' => 604,
            },
           {
            'ver' => 5,
            'count' => 469,
            }]}]
```

append code used is `$("#div").tmpl(items).appendTo("#divTable");`

I ve specified ${name} to get the printed output fruit and Veg, since name is another array, how do I get it printed??? Ive used ${values.ver}, it doesnt wrk...

Comment: Can we see the code that creates the `#div`-template?

Comment: <script id="div" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

${name}
${values.ver}
</script>

Comment: Ahh, one sec. Creating the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over an array within a `jQuery.tmpl`, you can use the [`{{each}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/)-template-language-construct, or [`{{tmpl}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/).

"Each" will just iterate over every item, automatically putting it in `$index` and `$value`. An example:

```
${name} <br />
{{each values}}
  ver: ${$value.ver} <br />
  count: ${$value.count} <br />
{{/each}}
```

Alternatively, "tmpl" will allow you to create a new template, meant specifically for the sub-arrays.

Comment: Ive also added a radio button with the jquery template, a user should only be allowed to select one radio button from each section                     ${name} <br />
{{each values}}    
  <input type="radio" name="radio">                                                                                                   ver: ${$value.ver} <br />
  count: ${$value.count} <br />
{{/each}}